# Count based on Month

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have created a new measure based on below formula which will do a Cumulative count of observation based on Period.

```
Measure = CALCULATE (
    COUNT ('Test'[Id] ),
    FILTER (
        ALLSELECTED ( 'Test' ),
        'Test'[Period] <= MAX ( 'Test'[Period] )
    )
)
```

I have applied Month has filter however my requirement is that if a new period start then count should start from 0 instead of previous value.
Eg:

| Id | Period | Month | temp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-30 | 2022-01 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-01-31 | 2022-01 | 2 |
| 3 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-02 | 1 |
| 4 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-02 | 2 |

Here temp is basically an example(I have created a Measure and not column). Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: How do you define a new period - is it the start of a new month? If so, you need a date table. Also, this is not a count as lines 3 and 4 would both show 2 in PBI if this was a count. Do you mean a rank instead?

Comment: Hello David, Yes new period would be start of new month. The reason why line 3 & 4 are showing 1 and 2 is because we are counting ID on the basis of month and then doing cumulative so on 1st Feb we have 1 I'd so count is 1 and on 2nd we have 1 I'd so count is 2(added 1 I'd from 1st feb)

Comment: That is not how PBI works for counting rows though. The only way to achieve your outcome is a RANKX with an option for ties. If you use count on identical periods, it will count them all i.e. 2 for lines 3 and 4. Either way, you should definitely have a date dimension table with a separate month column to help you with the reset between periods.